# Creating List APi for two models having many to one relationship

Tags: python, django, api, object, model

Here I have two models Ailines and Flight Details. The second model is many to one reln with Airlines model. When I create ListAPi view for Flight Details, the airline name doesnt appear on the apis, instead only id(pk) appears. Check the picture below, airlines only has number not airline name.

```
class Airlines(models.Model):
        Airline_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique= True)
        Email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique= True, help_text='example@gmail.com')
    
        Address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        Phone_Number = PhoneField(help_text='Contact phone number')
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Airline_Name


class FlightDetails(models.Model):
    Flight_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Aircraft_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    airlines = models.ForeignKey(Airlines, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Destination = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = "To")
    Destination_Code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Destination_Airport_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Here we can see in airlines it says 1, instead of airlines name.How can we solve it??

[image]

Comment: Could you add your code for your view and serializer please?

Answer (score 0):

in your serializers add depth = 2
you should class Airlines(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Airlines(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Airlines
        fields = ['Airline_Name']

class FlightDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    airline = Airlines()

    class Meta:
        model = Loan
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2
```

For getting the only **airline_name** you have to define it in airline serializer. I updated the code block.
The **depth** option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.

src: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: If I add depth =2, the api shows all the data of the airlines model. can we get the airline name only instead of showing the id?? ...also can you explain what does this depth mean actually?

Comment: class Airlines(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
        model = Airlines
        fields = ['Airline_Name']
        depth = 2